# Is it possible to open android installed share buttons from browser

Tags: android, share

I have a web page that have social share options. When the webpage is opened in android browser and share option is clicked, I want to open only installed share options of that android. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you opening webpage in webview or browser?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for something called Content Provider:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

You should be able to specify something like `<MyApp>://<MyContent>` into your HTML as href attribute, for example and start your app when the link is clicked (in a third party browser app).